# Python's json.dump() does not result in a beginning '[' bracket and ending ']' bracket

Tags: python, json

I am attempting to save a Python dictionary as a file in the .json format.
My desired output is:

```
[
    {
        "title": "An interesting title",
        "user_id": 22,
        "content": "This is a string of content"
    }
]
```

However, my actual output is:

```
{
    "title": "An interesting title",
    "user_id": 22,
    "content": "This is a string of content"
}
```

The code that I am using to create the .json is:

```
import json

def to_json():

        post = {
            'title': 'An interesting title',
            'user_id': 22,
            'content': 'This is a string of content'
        }

        with open('file.json', 'w') as file:
            json.dump(post, file, indent=4)

to_json()
```

I am confused why the json.dump() function does not automatically generate the square bracket characters, as I was under the impression that was the standard json format.

Comment: your impression is wrong: since the input doesn't contain an array you wouldn't get an array in the output
check the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table) on the transformation

Comment: I realize I am not using an array at any point--only a dictionary. However, in my experience with json files in the past they have always started with '[' and ended with ']', as seen in this example: https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/geoevent/latest/process-event-data/GUID-800BE275-3250-4BF9-93C2-B934C9AA468E-web.png

Comment: That's a specific json that contains an array of dictionaries; json files are not limited to arrays of dictionaries - simple dictionaries can be valid json files as well; hope that helps

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I guess I'm just super used to them being arrays of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[` and `]` braces in JSON mean array. So, if you want, program will be like this.

```py
import json

def to_json():

        post = {
            'title': 'An interesting title',
            'user_id': 22,
            'content': 'This is a string of content'
        }

        posts = [post] # Create array

        with open('file.json', 'w') as file:
            json.dump(posts, file, indent=4) # Dump to file

to_json()
```

The output will be as you desire.
*But, you are sure what you need array?*

Comment: No, as Mache explained I already had the proper format. Thanks for your time though!

Comment: Actually, it seems I did need it in array format for it to work the way I wanted. Your solution worked, thanks!